# dependent dropdown with jquery CODEIGNITER previous selection does not go away

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have this dependent dropdown working initially, but after the second selection the values of the first selection do not go away. Instead, the new values are just mixed with the previous values. I'm not familiar with jQuery but I need to finish this one as soon as possible.

first dropdown

```
            <select class="form-control" name = "PROV_ID" id = "PROV_ID">
              <option></option>
                <?php foreach ($content as $cs) {?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $cs->PROV_ID; ?>"><?php echo $cs->PROVINCE; ?></option>
                <?php } ?> 
            </select>
```

second dropdown

```
            <select name = 'CT_ID' id = 'CT_ID'>
                <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
            </select>
```

jquery

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $("#PROV_ID").change(function() {
        var PROVID = {"PROVID" : $('#PROV_ID').val()};
        console.log(PROVID);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: PROVID,
          url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown",

          success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, data){
            $('#CT_ID').append("<option value='"+data.CT_ID+"'>"+data.CITY+"</option>");
            });
           }
         });
       });
     });
</script>
```

I want to refresh the value of the second dropdown whenever I select a new option on the first dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the existing options before appending:

```
success: function(data){
    var select = $('#CT_ID');
    select.empty();
    $.each(data, function(i, option){
        select.append("<option value='"+option.CT_ID+"'>"+option.CITY+"</option>");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `append` to add HTML to the select element.  I would suggest using jQuery's `html` to set the HTML of the select (which will clear any existing option elements).  The added benefit here is that you are only doing one DOM manipulation, as opposed to one per option.

```
success: function(data){
    var $select = $('#CT_ID'),
      html = '';
    $.each(data, function(i, option) {
        html += "<option value='"+option.CT_ID+"'>"+option.CITY+"</option>";
    });
    $select.html(html);
}
```